# How to change prompt_alternatives_on flag in prolog from .plrc?

Tags: prolog

I can change `prompt_alternatives_on` flag in the REPL.

1. But how do I change this flag in .plrc?

Then I get

```
 permission to modify static_procedure `set_prolog_flag/2'
```

Goal: To not get the "More?" text for all the answers all the time. By changing the flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put :- (a colon and a hypen) in front of the line to execute it when the file is loaded.

```
:- set_prolog_flag(key, value).
```

This is true of any line of code in any source file that you want to have evaluated when the file is loaded instead of considered a new fact or rule (which causes the error because it attempts to redefine set_prolog_flag/2).

Comment: Yes, I know Prolog. I started learning it in university about 5 years ago and now some Prolog coding is part of my job, though not the main part.

Comment: ok, how do you feel about that? It's kind of rare. But extremely elegant. I think you should feel privileged. I would love to work with an AI language.